# How make pagination next and previous button in VB.NET for Acces database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am currently using a FlowLayoutPanel1 and UserControl1.vb to show me data from a database in Access.

I need 10 results to appear each time I hit the next button or the previous button.

This is my code:

Dim CLIENTES_GUARDADOS() As pedidos

```
Public Sub LISTAS_CLIENTES()
    COMANDOS.Parameters.Clear()
    CONECTAR.Close()
    CONECTAR.Open()
    COMANDOS.CommandText = "SELECT Count(PEDIDOS_CLIENTES.ID) AS Total  FROM PEDIDOS_CLIENTES"

    LEER = COMANDOS.ExecuteReader
    LEER.Read()

    Dim count As Integer = LEER(0)

    ReDim CLIENTES_GUARDADOS(count)

    CONECTAR.Close()
    CONECTAR.Open()
    COMANDOS.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 100 * FROM PEDIDOS_CLIENTES  Order By ID  DESC"

    LEER = COMANDOS.ExecuteReader

    FlowLayoutPanel5.Controls.Clear()

    Dim i As Integer = 0

    While LEER.Read() = True
        CLIENTES_GUARDADOS(i) = New pedidos()
        CLIENTES_GUARDADOS(i).ID = LEER("ID")
        CLIENTES_GUARDADOS(i).nombre.Text = LEER("NOMBRE")
        CLIENTES_GUARDADOS(i).NOMBRE_001 = LEER("NOMBRE")
        CLIENTES_GUARDADOS(i).APELLIDO_001 = LEER("APELLIDO")
        CLIENTES_GUARDADOS(i).APELLIDO.Text = LEER("APELLIDO")
        CLIENTES_GUARDADOS(i).TELEFONO_001 = LEER("TELEFONO")
        CLIENTES_GUARDADOS(i).PEDIDO = LEER("PEDIDO")
        CLIENTES_GUARDADOS(i).CANTIDAD = LEER("CANTIDAD")
        CLIENTES_GUARDADOS(i).COSTO = LEER("COSTO")
        CLIENTES_GUARDADOS(i).ADELANTO = LEER("ADELANTO")
        CLIENTES_GUARDADOS(i).FALTA = LEER("FALTA")
        CLIENTES_GUARDADOS(i).ESTADO_003 = LEER("ESTADO")
        CLIENTES_GUARDADOS(i).ESTADO_001.Text = LEER("ESTADO")
        CLIENTES_GUARDADOS(i).PAGADO = LEER("PAGADO")
        CLIENTES_GUARDADOS(i).FECHA = LEER("FECHA")
        CLIENTES_GUARDADOS(i).METODO_DE_PAGO.Text = LEER("FECHA")
        CLIENTES_GUARDADOS(i).HORA = LEER("HORA")

        FlowLayoutPanel5.Controls.Add(CLIENTES_GUARDADOS(i))

        i += 1
    End While

    CONECTAR.Close()
    Me.Refresh()
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I don't see your next and previous methods. Just a list method. Does this currently list the top 100 the records? I can see that you are running two queries, the first one sets the array size by the total number of records but then you only look at the top 100. You could skip the first query and just make the array size of 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim CLIENTES_GUARDADOS()
    Dim index As Integer = 0

    Private Sub ButtonNext_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonNext.Click
        If index < CLIENTES_GUARDADOS.Length - 2 Then
            index = index + 1
            DisplayCurrent()
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonPrevious_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonPrevious.Click
        If index > 0 Then
            index = index - 1
            DisplayCurrent()
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub DisplayCurrent()
        'fill panel with the CLIENTES_GUARDADOS(index)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Hi, how are you? I can send you my project so you can take a look at it, the answer is not completely clear to me, only if you have a little time, thank you very much for taking the time to respond

Comment: Your data is in an array CLIENTES_GUARDADOS().   As you press the next button you take each index of the array an put in to the panel.  So index in the current array position.  As you press the next index increases but you never want to go larger than the array size.  Likewise when you press previous index should decrease but never go negative.

Comment: Thank you very much for responding. Your help was very helpful. Greetings from Spain